# Laravel form select onChange value save to databse via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a dropdown list generated by the following code in controller (FocalController.php):

```
  $focalData = DB::table('role_users')->orderBy('users.id','DESC')
            ->leftJoin('users', function($join){
                $join->on('role_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                $join->on('role_users.role_id', '=', DB::raw("'1'"));
            })
            ->select('users.id',DB::raw('CONCAT(users.name) AS focal'))
            ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->get();

    foreach($focalData as $data):
        $focals[$data->id] = $data->focal;
    endforeach;
```

in the view, I have the following block generating the drop-down list:

```
{!! Form::select('focal', [''=>'select focal']+ collect($focals)->toArray() , $project_focal, array('class' => 'form-control','onchange'=>'changeFocal(this, '.$project->id.')' ))!!}
```

[image]

I want to submit the drop-down value onChange and save the value using AJAX.

My ajax for the form submission is following:

```
    function changeFocal(e,project_id) {

        var focal_id = $("#e").val();
        var project_id = $("#project_id").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            data: "focal_id=" + e + "&project_id=" + project_id,
            url:  "{{ URL::to('admin/focal') }}",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);$("#msg").html("New Focal Assigned.");
            }
        });
    }
```

My route is:

```
Route::post('admin/focal/','FocalController@saveFocal');
```

the `saveFocal` function in my `FocalController` is:

```
public function saveFocal(Request $request){
        $focal_id = $request->focal_id;
        $project_id = $request->project_id;    
        $project = Project::find('idea_id', $project_id)
                    ->update([
                        'focal' => $focal_id,
                        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                    ]);
        @\App\Common::createAccessLog($project->focal, "Update Project Focal for Project#" . $project->idea_id . "(" . $project->name . ")");
        return view('admin/focal');
    }
```

I am getting the following error in console:
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I save the select data to database with ajax along with a success message.

Comment: Try using `post` instead `put`and add `_token` for csrf

Comment: that throws "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: You're Route is set up to be a `post` route yet your ajax method is submitting a `put` request? Also, what is the 500 error you mentioned above?

Comment: I corrected the ajax method to 'post' and added 'csrf' token. Now the ajax call goes through and shows the success message. But the data is not being saved in database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use POST instead of PUT

Also make sure the route you are sending your request to is valid and exists

Below are few corrections:

```
function changeFocal(e,project_id) {

    var focal_id = $(e).val(); //correction
    var project_id = $("#project_id").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        data: "focal_id=" + focal_id + "&project_id=" + project_id, //correction
        url:  "{{ URL::to('admin/focal') }}",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);$("#msg").html("New Focal Assigned.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I corrected the ajax method to 'post' and added 'csrf' token. Now the ajax call goes through and shows the success message. But the data is not being saved in database!

Comment: console.log the project id and see if its picking the right id.
function changeFocal(e,project_id) {

    var focal_id = $(e).val(); //correction
    var project_id = $("#project_id").val();
console.log(project_id)

Comment: says 'undefined'. So the project_id is not reaching the ajax call?

Comment: Yes, you will need to find the correct way to pass project_id in the request

Answer (score 0):

Ude `where` Clause instead `find`

```
  Project::where(
```

`find` works on primary key